# PHP date() - error in finding date in between

Tags: php, date

I'm using the following code to see if a date falls between 2 other dates.

```
    public function dateCompare($date1, $date2) 
    {

    $interimDate = date('d/m/Y');
    $StartDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date1);
    $EndDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date2);



    if ($interimDate > $StartDate && $interimDate < $EndDate)
    {
      echo 'Falls during given period';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Does not fall during given period';
    }
```

The two dates passed as follows

```
dateCompare('01/08/14', '30/12/14');
```

For some reason I continually get the message that todays date does not fall between the given period. I have checked the servers datetime and it is correct. Is anyone able to point out what exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Just replace $interimDate with = new DateTime('today');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2 letter years, so it should be lower case `y` for your format: `d/m/y`.
Also, make `$interimDate` equal to a `new DateTime()` object so you can compare properly.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Have edited as such but am still faced with the same problem!

Comment: @NVix: this should work and should be accepted answer. Be more specific what you have changed and what doesnt work...